# How to make an array come out as a word not numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I'm building a bin size calculator and I need the type of bin too come out as a word not numbers

I tried making separate string's for each bin name, but did not succeed.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int i;

    cout << "Welcome to Jasons bin size measurer!\n\nPlease answer the following questions: " << endl;

    cout << " Please Tell us your waste type " << endl << "By typing the corrosponding number: " << endl;

    char waste[11][50] = { " ", "General Waste = 1","Mixed Heavy Waste = 2", "Timber Waste = 3","Green Garden Waste = 4 ","Soil/Dirt = 5","Clean Fill/Hard Fill = 6","Concrete only = 7","Bricks only = 8", "Cardboard/Paper = 9","Metal only = 10" };

    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        cout << waste[i] << "\n";
    }

    cin >> waste[i];

    int length = 0;
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    cout << "\nPlease enter the length: ";
    cin >> length;

    cout << endl << "Please enter the width: ";
    cin >> width;

    cout << endl << "Please enter the height: ";
    cin >> height;

    int volume = length * width * height;

    cout << endl;


    if (volume < 3) {
        cout << "A 2m " << waste << endl;

    }

    if (volume < 4 && volume > 2)  {
        cout << "\nA 3m bin ";

    }

    if (volume < 5 && volume > 3) {
        cout << "\nA 4m bin will meet your requirements";

    }

    if (volume < 7 && volume > 4) {
        cout << "\nA 6m bin will meet your requirements";

    }

    if (volume < 9 && volume > 6) {
        cout << "\nA 8m bin will meet your requirements";

    }

    if (volume < 11 && volume > 8) {
        cout << "\nA 10m bin will meet your requirements";

    }

    if (volume < 13 && volume > 10) {
        cout << "\nA 12m bin will meet your requirements";

    }

    if (volume < 22 && volume > 12) {
        cout << "\nA 21m bin will meet your requirements";

    }

    if (volume < 25 && volume > 21) {
        cout << "\nA 24m bin will meet your requirements";

    }

    if (volume < 32 && volume > 24) {
        cout << "\nA 31m bin will meet your requirements";

    }

    if (volume > 31) {
        cout << "\nUnfortunatly we do not have that bin size";
        return 0;
    }

}
```

I Expect the output to be `x bin will meet your requirements(bin name)`
However it come out as `X bin will meet your requirements 008FFA1C`.

Comment: Also I would like some assistance on how too optimize the code

Comment: The code you show doesn't print anything after the word "requirements" - neither the bin name nor a number. The code you actually run, one that produces undesired output, must be different from the code shown.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik when I run it, it comes out as how I described, I am using visual studio c++

Comment: `cout << "A 2m " << waste` doesn't make sense. `waste` is an array of strings, not a single string. What exactly do you expect this line to print? In fact, it prints the address of `waste`, as a hex number.

Comment: I would like it to print the selected array within waste, so like If I enter General Waste it prints, "A 2m (General Waste)"

Comment: Ah. In fact, `cin >> waste[i];` already exhibits undefined behavior, since by that time `i == 11` which is outside the bounds of `waste` array. That line makes no sense. If you want the user to input a number, surely by now you know how to declare an integer variable and to read its value from user input.

Comment: I want the user to input a number, the number he inputs represents each array; So I need help on displaying the chosen array

Comment: Once you have the variable, say, `int k;`, with the value between 1 and 10, you can print the corresponding element of the array with `std::cout << waste[k];`

Comment: Whats the point of std:: etc; If i'm 'using namespace std;' ? And also does the user input the value for int k?

Comment: Well, you prompt the user to "typ[e] the corrosponding [sic] number". Sounds to me like you expect the user to enter an integral value, which would be reasonable to collect in an integral variable, would it not?

Comment: yes, I expect the user to enter the assigned integer as prompted, and that integer will show out as the assigned word/words. Please explain how to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in your code. Let's start with the fact you allocate 11 strings in the array but you read the 12th. Starting this moment everything could happen, this is undefined behavior.

Next, you return 0 only if `volume > 31` which is definitely an error.

Finally, you output the 2 dimentional array instead of the element of the array:

```
cout << "A 2m " << waste << endl;
```

Did you mean

```
cout << "A 2m " << waste[0] << endl;
```

or something like that?

Comment: 1) I want the user to input a number, the number he inputs represents each array; So I need help on displaying the chosen array.     2) I made a mulitdimensional area,first [11] = 11 words/ grouped words. And [50] represents max character limit.

Comment: @LectroFiy If you want to input a number, then just input a number. `cin >> i;`

Comment: @LectroFiy You are reinventing a wheel in a very error prone way. Use `std::string` instead.

Comment: I would like the inputed number to be linked to the assigned array; And use std::string instead of char?

Comment: @LectroFiy you may input a number, then use this number as an index. `int k; cin >> k; // use waste[k];`

Comment: If you wish, you even may create a new variable: `char * wasteSelected = waste[k];`

Comment: what does '*' after char mean? Sorry im new.

Comment: I Understand now thanks, one more thing, what format do I export it in?

Comment: Pointer to a char. You may think that this is a string.

Comment: @LectroFiy Format? Export? What do you mean?

Comment: I would like to export this code on too a blog post, so what format do I export it in? eg; .dll, .png etc;

Comment: I'm not, I'm new, started a week ago.